# Tclx: Is there any way to save history using commandloop

Tags: shell, tcl

In tclx, is it possible to save history in interactive mode and access the interactive console for sending tab in linux shell?

```
package require Tclx
proc customPrompt { } {
    return "TC> "
}
commandloop -interactive on -prompt1 customPrompt
```

Comment: If it's using the `history` system, it ought to be fairly simple…

Comment: Which interactive console? Which shell? And why send a tab to it?

Answer (score 0):

I wrap a function around tclsh:

```
tclsh() {
    if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
        command tclsh "$@"
    else
        rlwrap tclsh
    fi
}
```

[`rlwrap`](http://man.cx/rlwrap) gives you the readline command line editing, just like you have at your shell prompt.